# how to escape backslash in typesafe ConfigFactory?

Tags: java

I need to create a `com.typesafe.config.Config` object out of a json string containing windows path which includes backslash "\".

Below is my code

```
private Config getReportNotificationStringForOrg(String eachOrgId,
        String type, String subType, String expiryDateTime, String title,
        String content, String contentType, long startDateTime,
        String description) {
    Config requestForQueryReplace = ConfigFactory
            .parseString("{ \"org_id\":\""
                    + eachOrgId
                    + "\",  \"type\": \""
                    + type
                    + "\",  \"subtype\": \""
                    + subType
                    + "\", \"expiry_datetime\": \""
                    + expiryDateTime
                    + "\", \"title\": \""
                    + title
                    + "\", \"content\": \""
                    + content
                    + "\", \"content_type\": \""
                    + contentType
                    + "\", \"start_datetime\": \""
                    + startDateTime
                    + "\", \"created_by\": \"machine_generated\", \"description\": \""
                    + description + "\"}");

    String notificationInput = eqp.getDataPopulatedQueryUsingType("notification.notification_insert_input", requestForQueryReplace);

    return ConfigFactory.parseString(notificationInput);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenerateNotificationStoreInESImpl obj = new GenerateNotificationStoreInESImpl();
    System.out.println(obj.getReportNotificationStringForOrg("LUNAAA", "", "", "", "", "", "", 1494374400000, "<Agent installation directory>\\jre\\lib"));

}
```

This throws below error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: String: 1: in value for key 'description': backslash followed by 'j', this is not a valid escape sequence (quoted strings use JSON escaping, so use double-backslash \\ for literal backslash)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.nextToken(Parser.java:179)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.nextTokenIgnoringNewline(Parser.java:199)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.consolidateValueTokens(Parser.java:277)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseObject(Parser.java:653)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseValue(Parser.java:408)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parse(Parser.java:818)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parse(Parser.java:34)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:199)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:187)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:171)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:165)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parse(Parseable.java:204)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseString(ConfigFactory.java:790)
    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseString(ConfigFactory.java:794)
    at com.abc.xyz.event.action.notification.GenerateNotificationStoreInESImpl.getReportNotificationStringForOrg(GenerateNotificationStoreInESImpl.java:83)
    at com.abc.xyz.event.action.notification.GenerateNotificationStoreInESImpl.main(GenerateNotificationStoreInESImpl.java:110)
```

How to escape "\" backslash to use with com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory?

Comment: Have you tried using \\ ?

Comment: @Paolo: I am already using `\\` see main method

Comment: A double back-slash, as @Ivan Pronin said in the answer. Or even 3 in some case

Comment: @PaoloForgia:Ihave tried giving 3 backslashes `\\\jre...` program gives an exception. Says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )`

Comment: @user801116 Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is stated in the error message, just read it carefully: `quoted strings use JSON escaping, so use double-backslash \\ for literal backslash`

Comment: In total you should use 3 \\\ to escape one \

Comment: If I try giving 3 backslashes `\\\jre...` program is not compiling. Says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: Have you tried `<Agent installation directory>\\/jre\\/lib` ?

Comment: This works, but it gives me forward slash instead of backslash `<Agent installation directory>/jre/lib`

Comment: Forward slash `/` is for linux and as mentioned in question I am entering windows path which has backward slash `\\`